# Why my excel macro doesn't invoke external program

Tags: excel, vba

I have a batch file in my Windows10 "C" drive that creates several files in the current directory. I have created a macro in an excel document to invoke this batch file. I have assigned the macro to an excel button and saved the excel document in a ".xlsm" file. Upon pressing this button a Window Command Prompt starts up for a few seconds and disappears. If the batch file runs, I should then see several files created in the current directory, which I don't see at this point. Any ideas why the batch program is not invoking?
Here is the code in the macro:

```
Sub runBatchFile()

'

' runBatchFile Macro

'

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q

'

Dim FileN As String

FileN = "C:\Users\s3\runit.bat"

Call Shell(FileN, 3)

End Sub
```

I am running office 2019 on Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the batch file is not called? I took your code and the batch file I used was called. You even mention that you get a command prompt. So, I guess, the batch file is the problem and does not do what you expect. Or the working directory of your batch file is different from your current directory.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The batch file works, when called from the command line. Both ".xlsm" and the .bat files are in the same directory. In addition, I have included the full path to the batch file in the macro, to make sure the .bat file is found by the macro. The Command prompt opens and closes so fast that I can't see the message it's displaying.

Comment: Check the working directory of your batch file. Just add a `cd `and `pause`at the beginning and/or end of your batch file and you will see the messages.

Comment: What does **cd** without any path do?

Comment: It shows the working directory of the batch file.

Comment: Thanks the pause helped me to see the error. The batch runs a program that opens an excel sheet called input.xlsx. When the batch is called from the command prompt it works fine. Per my client request, I have added a macro and a button to input.xlsx to call the batch (because she doesn't know how to work with the window's command prompt) and I was forced to save it as input.xlsm. Now when the batch is invoked by the button in the **input.xlsm**, the program can not find the **input.xlsx**. Would you happen to know the workaround?  All the needed files are in the same working directory. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, how should I know? I do not have the details of your batch file nor of your client request. If the file ending is now **xlsm** why would you want to work with a file ending in **xlsx**. Does the file **input.xlsx** exist after all? And whatever the batch file is doing why can't you do it with VBA then?

Comment: The **input.xlsx** does exist in the same working directory. When you add a button and a macro to an excel document, excel saves everything in the **".xlms"** file instead of the original **".xlsx"**, not sure why? If the user forces it to save the excel into the original **.xlsx** file then macro would not be saved, which defeats the purpose of creating the macro.

Comment: Yes, of course, an excel file ending in xlsx cannot contain a macro. Again, based on the information you are giving I am afraid I cannot help. The question in the post is solved resp. it was never like described in the post _Why my excel macro doesn't invoke external program_

Comment: Yes, the question is solved. Do you need to put it in an answer before I accept or can I accept the comment? Thanks again

Comment: I am not after the "points". So, nothing else to do.

Comment: @Storax: You actually solved the problem. The **cd** helped me to just realize somehow the button has changed the working directory to c:\users\s3\Downloads, so I modified the batch file to change to the actual working directory and now everything works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Batch file may contain file manipulation commands or other things that are only known to CMD.  Why don't you try invoking your Batch file under CMD like this:

```
    Shell("cmd /k C:\Users\s3\runit.bat")
```

Read up on CMD options here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd